# Passing float value from C program to assembler level program using only integer registers?

Tags: c, assembly, floating-point, x86-64

For my class we are writing a simple asm program (with C and AT&T x86-64) that prints all the bits of an integer or float. I have the integer part working fine. For the float part my professor has instructed us to pass the float value only using integer registers. Not too sure why we're not allowed to use float registers. Regardless, does anyone have ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: Which part is causing you problem? `*(uint32_t*)&float_variable` Likely not standard C, but whatever :) You could also just pass its address of course as `void*` and that would then work properly for both integer and float and would be standard compliant too.

Comment: @Jester Use `union` to make it standard.

Comment: Pass to printf?  Just use `mov` to pass it as an integer to a `%x` conversion, for example.

Answer (score 1):

> my professor has instructed us to pass the float value only using integer registers.

A simple approach is to copy the `float` into an integer using `memcpy()`

```
float f = ...;
assert(sizeof f == sizeof(uint32_t));

uint32_t u;
memcpy(&u, &f, sizeof u);
foo(u);
```

Another is to use a `union`.  Perhaps using a *compound literal*.

```
void foo (uint32_t);

int main() {
  float f;
  assert(sizeof f == sizeof(uint32_t));

  //  v----------- compound literal -----------v
  foo((union { float f; uint32_t u; }) { .f = f}.u);
  //   ^------ union object ------- ^
}
```

Both require that the integer type used and the `float` are the same size.

Other issues include insuring the correct endian of the two, yet very commonly the endians of the `float` and integer will match.

Comment: Fun fact: x86-64 System V passes a union of `{float; uint32_t};` the same way it passes `uint32_t`, so for variadic functions like printf you could just pass the union object and ignore compiler warnings about mismatch with conversions.